# How can I populate a table from another with a look up for each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
    [WordId]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]          VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp] (
    [HeaderWord]    VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [OtherWord]     VARCHAR (20) NULL
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordRelationship] (
    [HeaderWordId] INT NOT NULL,
    [OtherWordId]  INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_WordRelationship] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([HeaderWordId] ASC, [OtherWordId] ASC)
);
```

The third table is empty. Is there a way with SQL and not with needing a cursor that I could populate the WordRelationship table with the Id values of the Header and Other word? Note that in some case there may not be an OtherWord for each row in Temp2. Also every HeaderWord and OtherWord has an entry in the Word table.

Here's some sample data for the Word Table

```
WordId  Word
------  ----
5472    abandon
5473    abandoned
5474    abandoning
5475    abandonment
5476    abandons    
5477    abstraction 
5478    abstractions
5479    abstractly
5480    abstracts
```

Here's some sample data for the Temp Table

```
Header  Other
Word    Word
------- ----------
abandon abandoned
abandon abandoning
abandon abandonment
abandon abandons
```

Comment: can you explain it with some sample data?

Comment: Well... [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) rules!

Comment: Learn about `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO WordRelationship
SELECT DISTINCT a.WordId, b.WordId
FROM Temp t
INNER JOIN Word a
    ON t.HeaderWord = a.Word
INNER JOIN Word b
    ON t.OtherWord = b.Word
```

You need `DISTINCT` cause there may be duplicates in `Temp` table. Also I recommend `INNER JOIN`, it shall eliminate null's if there are no words from `Temp` table in `Word` table.

Comment: Since 'there may not be an OtherWord for each row in Temp' and because OtherWord is nullable,so i thought theses lines are wanted, and took LEFT JOIN for OtherWord,

Comment: Both columns are part of primary key, as I remember they can not be nullable in that case. But I can be mistaken, please, correct me, if I am.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WordRelationship]
 SElECT a.WordId, b.WordId from [dbo].[Temp] t
 JOIN [dbo].{Word] a on t.HeaderWord = a.Word  
 LEFT JOIN [dbo].{Word] b on t.OtherWord = b.Word
```

**EDIT**

removed LEFT in Join over Headerword since it is a not null field in WordRelationship.